# Get username with javascript to the value of the clause where in sql select

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I don't think that I have to use javascript here. But if this is the solution, I will take it.

I am able to echo the SESSION of Username in my pages. But when I try to call it again in order to get the detail of the user information, it doesn't work.

Here is the scenario when it doesn't work:

- I echo the session of username in the clause of sql select with the code bellow:

  ```
  $member_email = $_SESSION['member_email'];
  $member_name = $_SESSION['member_name'];
  $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM member_registry WHERE member_name='$member_name' And member_email='$member_email'");
  $obj = $results->fetch_object();

  echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><input type="text" readonly name="member_address" value="'.$obj->member_address_satu.'"/></td><tr>';
  ```

It works when I input the value of username directly in the clause of where of sql select

```
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM member_registry WHERE member_name='Someone Name'");
```

I am very sure that the Session of username is fine. Becuase when I echo it, it shows the username:

```
        <li>You Login as <?php echo $member_name;?></li>
```

If I can't use clause of `WHERE member_name='$member_name'` then I think I can use javascript to send the text from `You login as <?php echo $member_name;?` as the string to the clause.

How to do this, and how to solve this problem cleanly. Please help, I am just learning and learning and learning.

I hope anyone understand what I am asking here. Many thanks for all of that.

**[UPDATED]**

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
$member_name = $_SESSION['member_name'];
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM member_registry WHERE member_name=?");
$bind=$mysqli->bind_param('s',$member_name);
$mysqli->execute(); 
$obj = $results->fetch_object();

if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
    $total = 0;
    echo '<form action="cart-post-config.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">';
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td></td>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="member_name" value="'.$member_name.'"/>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_name[]" value="'.$cart_itm["name"].'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_price[]" value="'.$cart_itm["price"].'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_quantity[]" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'"/></td>';                           
                    $totalPerEach = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);

                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_eachTotal[]" value="'.$totalPerEach.'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td>View Save Delete</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
    }


    echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><input type="text" readonly name="member_address" value="'.$obj->member_address_satu.'"/></td><tr>';                          

    echo '<tr><td colspan="6" style="text-align: right; background: yellowgreen;"><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td><tr>';
    echo '</form>';//close the form
}
else {
    echo 'Your Cart is empty'; }
?>
```

This is at the header of the page.

```
<?php
include("config.php");  
$member_name = $_SESSION['member_name'];
$member_email = $_SESSION['member_email'];
?>
    <ul id="list-logo-menu">
        <li>Live Chat</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>You Login as <?php echo $member_name;?></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

[UPDATE 2]

```
                    <tr class="boder-table">
                        <td width="32"><u>No</u></td>
                        <td width="174"><u>Product Name</u></td>
                        <td width="103"><u>Price</u></td>
                        <td width="103"><u>Quantity</u></td>
                        <td width="103"><u>Total Price</u></td>
                        <td width="142"><u>Mark</u></td>
                    </tr>



 $member_name = $_SESSION['member_name'];
 $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM member_registry WHERE member_name=? ");
 $bind=$mysqli->bind_param('s',$member_name);//bind them here

 $result= $mysqli->execute();//execute your query
 print_r($result).'<br/>';


 if($result->num_rows<0)
 {
 $mysqli->error;
 } else echo '<br/>'.$mysqli->num_rows;


if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
    include_once("config.php");
    $total = 0;
    echo '<form action="cart-post-config.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">';
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td></td>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="member_name" value="'.$member_name.'"/>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_name[]" value="'.$cart_itm["name"].'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_price[]" value="'.$cart_itm["price"].'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_quantity[]" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'"/></td>';                           
                    $totalPerEach = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);

                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_eachTotal[]" value="'.$totalPerEach.'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td>View Save Delete</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
    }


    echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><input type="text" readonly name="member_address" value="'.$obj->member_address_satu.'"/></td><tr>';                          

    echo '<tr><td colspan="6" style="text-align: right; background: yellowgreen;"><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td><tr>';
    echo '</form>';//close the form
}
else {
    echo 'Your Cart is empty'; }
?>
            </table>
```

Comment: just debug it yourself, its not hard to do anyways: `var_dump($member_name, $member_email);` before `$results` line. and why not bind those vars instead. and as always: always turn on error reporting

Comment: But why it works when I input the value of user-name directly?

Comment: @klaudia, I have posted answer as per your requirment,Please check it & let me know if you still have any issues !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just move the location where I should write the new sql statements.

```
<?php


if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
    include_once("config.php");
    $total = 0;
    echo '<form action="cart-post-config.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">';
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td></td>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="member_name" value="'.$member_name.'"/>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_name[]" value="'.$cart_itm["name"].'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_price[]" value="'.$cart_itm["price"].'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_quantity[]" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'"/></td>';                           
                    $totalPerEach = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);

                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_eachTotal[]" value="'.$totalPerEach.'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td>View Save Delete</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
    }

    $member_name = $_SESSION['member_name'];
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM member_registry WHERE member_name='$member_name'");
    $obj = $results->fetch_object();
    echo '<span class="product-name">'.$obj->member_address_satu.'</span></br>';

    echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><input type="text" readonly name="member_address" value="'.$obj->member_address_satu.'"/></td><tr>';                          

    echo '<tr><td colspan="6" style="text-align: right; background: yellowgreen;"><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td><tr>';
    echo '</form>';//close the form
}
else {
    echo 'Your Cart is empty'; }
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `bind_param`

```
        $member_name = $_SESSION['member_name'];
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM member_registry WHERE member_name=?");
    $bind=$mysqli->bind_param('s',$member_name);//bind them here

$result= $mysqli->execute();//execute your query
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($row).'<br/>'; // to see the result. 


if($result->num_rows<0)
{
    $mysqli->error;//to check the error
} else echo '<br/>'.$mysqli->num_rows;//to print the row.


if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
    include_once("config.php");
    $total = 0;
    echo '<form action="cart-post-config.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">';
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td></td>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="member_name" value="'.$member_name.'"/>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_name[]" value="'.$cart_itm["name"].'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_price[]" value="'.$cart_itm["price"].'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_quantity[]" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'"/></td>';                           
                    $totalPerEach = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);

                    echo '<td><input type="text" readonly name="product_eachTotal[]" value="'.$totalPerEach.'"/></td>';
                    echo '<td>View Save Delete</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
    }


    echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><input type="text" readonly name="member_address" value="'.$obj->member_address_satu.'"/></td><tr>';                          

    echo '<tr><td colspan="6" style="text-align: right; background: yellowgreen;"><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td><tr>';
    echo '</form>';//close the form
}
else {
    echo 'Your Cart is empty'; }
?>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

@klaudia,First check your mysqli connection to database is proper or not. The sample connection for mysqli as below.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","mysql_user","mysql_password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Then Check your session details proper or not via print session.

```
echo $_SESSION['member_email'];
echo $_SESSION['member_name'];
```

Then you need to fire below query as per your requirement.

```
//Below is sample membername & email,you can put your session data in below two line.

$member_email = 'user@user.com';
$member_name = 'test';

//For Your scenario it would be like below. (Rememeber you need to put session_start() in top of the page)

$member_email = $_SESSION['member_email'];
$member_name = $_SESSION['member_name'];

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM member_registry WHERE member_name='$member_name' And member_email='$member_email'");
$obj = $results->fetch_object();
echo "<pre>";print_r($obj);
```

Please try above & let me know if still any issues.

Comment: Hi sir, thankns for helping me. But this code is not working because this is what I have when I asked the question. Please, help me again. And thank you very much.

Comment: @klaudia, Can you please go through my steps ? 1. check connection. 2. check session data 3. fire query. Because its working fine at my end !

Comment: @klaudia, Can you please also show config.php file code in question ?

Comment: `<?php

$db_username = 'klaudia';
$db_password = 'klaudia';
$db_name = 'klaudia';
$db_host = 'com';
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);
?>`

Comment: @klaudia, can you please below line to your config.php file.          // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

Comment: The config works fine because I get all the session from here. Session of products and session of username.

Comment: @klaudia, so what errors you're getting on your page ? can you please tell me ?

Comment: There is no error, sir. But something is not working while the rest is working as expected. What is not working is when I use the session name as a value of the new sql select statements. Please, sir, have a look to my question. I am very sure you can help me (your reputation is high :) ) if you try to read it again.

Comment: @klaudia, Can you please put below line in your top of page & check errors on your page. ini_set('display_errors',1); So this statement turns errors on your page so you can recognize errors.

Comment: @klaudia,Also can you please print session before use it in to query ?